# Display main menu expanded in footer, drop down in header

Tags: 7, routes, theming, navigation, blocks

I'm trying to show the Main menu in two places, once as a dropdown menu at the top, then again in the footer as a fully expanded (non-collapsible) set of links. I'm using the Superfish module to handle the top menu, and Menu Blocks to place the menu in my footer region. I'm using D7 and am sub-themeing the Bootstrap theme. Ideally, I'm looking for a way to simply output the Main menu as a very simple unordered list of links, without any of the dropdown classes or scripting applied to it. Where would be the best place to do this? I tried overriding `theme_menu_link` but that didn't seem right (since I can't figure out how to get the region.)

Comment: [How to print a custom menu in Drupal 7?][1] - replace menu-site-menu to main-menu


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824093/how-to-print-a-custom-menu-in-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks for the link! So there is no way to do this without editing the template? (I don't have a problem with this, just curious.)

Comment: Unfortunately, that only gives one level of the menu, I need all the submenu items as well.

Answer (score 1):

We use the [menu_block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module for this - it lets you create unlimited menu blocks and control menu depth and other options.

> This module provides configurable blocks of menu links with advanced features not available in Drupal 8 core.
>
> Drupal 8 core allows you to display blocks of menu links starting with any desired level of a menu and limited to any desired depth.
>
> And this Menu Block module provides additional configuration so you can choose to expand all menu links with children or to root the menu tree to a specific menu item.
>
> The Drupal 7 version of this module provides all of these features since Drupal 7 core does not have any of this functionality.

So I just noticed you're already using menu_block. You can add multiple_menu blocks - you should simply be able to add a new menu_block for the main-menu on your site and use that one in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up using. It works, but I'm not confident it's the "right" way to do it. The menu will never be more than 2 levels deep, so it's not a recursive solution by design. This is in my `page.tpl.php` right above `print render($page['footer']);`

```
$tree = menu_build_tree('main-menu');
$output = "<ul>";
foreach ($tree as $item) {
  $menu_link = $item['link'];
  $link = sprintf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>', $menu_link['link_path'], $menu_link['link_title'], $menu_link['link_title']);
  $element = "<li>".$link;
  if (isset($item['below']) && count($item['below'])) {
    $element .= "<ul>";
    foreach ($item['below'] as $sub_item) {
      $sub_menu_link = $sub_item['link'];
      $sub_link = sprintf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>', $sub_menu_link['link_path'], $sub_menu_link['link_title'], $sub_menu_link['link_title']);
      $sub_element = "<li>".$sub_link."</li>";
      $element .= $sub_element;
    }
    $element .= "</ul>";
  }
  $element .= "</li>";
  $output .= $element;
}
output .= "</ul>";
print $output;
```